# Does f(x) = 2*x + 1 belong to $o(X)$?

Tags: nonlinear-functions, little-o

Suppose a function f: R -> R defined as
f(x) = mx + c for some m, c > 0 and x in R. Does f(x) belong to o(x)?

If the answer is "NO", can we conclude that o(x) does not properly contain the set of sub-linear functions?

The reason I'm asking this: 
It is easy to see that f(x) is sub-linear because
f(x1) + f(x2) = mx1 + c + mx2 + c > m(x1+x2) + c = f(x1+x2).
But lim x-> infinity f(x)/x = 2. In this sense f(x) is not in o(x). But o(x) represents the set of sub linear functions. That's where my confusion comes from.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? Does the definition of o(x) help? Why not? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the update, your question makes perfect sense now. As it was before, it looked like copy&paste computer science homework, which is probably why it gathered so many downvotes. It is actually a good question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, f(x) = 2x + 1 ∉ o(x).

I think your confusion comes from the definition of **sublinear**. Linear algebra and computer science use [two different meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function) here:

- In linear algebra, sublinear functions are a generalization of linear functions, i.e. **every linear function is a sublinear function**. As you have shown in the question, your f(x) satisfies the *subadditivity* criterion.
- In computer science, *linear* and *sublinear* describe the **asymptotic behavior**. A sublinear function is a function which grows slower than *every* linear function, given a large enough input. Thus, **no linear function is a sublinear function**.

Thus, your f(x) is sublinear w.r.t. linear algebra, but it is not sublinear w.r.t. computer science.